# MarkLogic PojoQueryBuilder is not working with jboss EAP

Tags: java, xml, spring, jboss, marklogic

I have a springboot application works with MarkLogic database. I am using MarkLogic JAVA client api v 3.0.1.

I have a PojoRepository which works fine for all the other tasks except search with Jboss EAP 6.4.0
I tried with embedded server of spring boot and separate tomcat server it works fine. My Code snips are as below:

```
@Override
    public List<Property> findAll() {
        List<Property> list = new ArrayList<>();
        PojoQueryBuilder<Property> qb1 = repository.getQueryBuilder();
        StructuredQueryDefinition query1 = qb1.and(
                qb1.collection(PROPERTY_COLLECTION),
                qb1.value("archived", false));
        PojoPage<Property> pg = repository.search(query1, 1);
        Iterator<Property> it = pg.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            list.add(it.next());
        }
        System.out.println("list: " + list);
        return list;

    }
```

> Error Log is as below:
>
> 17:18:50,802 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/v1/preference_categories] due to exception [Local message: search failed: Bad Request. Server Message: REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: Invalid query structure (check namespace): preference_category.json]: com.marklogic.client.FailedRequestException: Local message: search failed: Bad Request. Server Message: REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Invalid parameter: Invalid query structure (check namespace): preference_category.json
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices$JerseySearchRequest.getResponse(JerseyServices.java:2206) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.getBulkDocumentsImpl(JerseyServices.java:869) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.getBulkDocuments(JerseyServices.java:744) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.search(DocumentManagerImpl.java:500) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.JSONDocumentImpl.search(JSONDocumentImpl.java:26) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.PojoRepositoryImpl.search(PojoRepositoryImpl.java:340) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.marklogic.client.impl.PojoRepositoryImpl.search(PojoRepositoryImpl.java:308) [java-client-api-3.0.1.jar:]
>       at com.optum.pma.service.impl.PrefereceCategoryServiceImpl.findAll(PrefereceCategoryServiceImpl.java:217) [classes:]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy127.findAll(Unknown Source)
>       at com.optum.pma.controller.PreferenceCategoryController.allPCs(PreferenceCategoryController.java:139) [classes:]
>       at com.optum.pma.controller.PreferenceCategoryController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$19b9caad.invoke() [classes:]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at com.optum.pma.controller.PreferenceCategoryController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$10723d75.allPCs() [classes:]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]

If anyone can have way out... any kind of advice is highly appreciated ...
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one for your valuable comment, I tried to check the log in Marklogic ErrorLog it didn't show any thing and I tried to log the reproduce the same error form other approach but I cannot do it. In Jboss EAP only I get the error message:

Forwarding to error page from request [/v1/preference_categories] due to exception 
[Local message: search failed: Bad Request. Server Message: REST-INVALIDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) 
Invalid parameter: Invalid query structure (check namespace):

```
<query xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<collection-query>
<uri>preference_category.json</uri>
</collection-query>
</query>
```

But, when I changed my JAVA Client API version from 3.0.1 to 3.0.5 it start working. 
I don't know what specific Woodstox and OOTB Java Stax implementation shipped this version. But the good thing for me is it worked fine. If I found some thing specific I will post here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be some version conflict with the Jersey libraries that the ML Java Client API uses, and which I'm assuming that JBoss packages up as well. But it's hard to say with that error message.

Things I'd try to debug - take a look at the payload being sent to MarkLogic to see if something looks wrong; check the MarkLogic ErrorLog.txt for additional info; worst case, add some xdmp:log statements to the REST API code included in MarkLogic to log what MarkLogic is receiving before the search is attempted. Any tool for looking at HTTP traffic should help here as well.

Check JBoss's classpath too to see if it's using a particular version of Jersey. You could try a simple Main program that uses the Java Client API and that version of Jersey and see if it works or if it reproduces the error. That's another technique to try - try to reproduce the error outside of JBoss with a classpath that mirrors what JBoss uses.

Comment: I agree with @rjrudin.  I'd look for Woodstox on the classpath.  We've found several ways that Woodstox implements the Stax API differently than our code expected, so we had to find work-arounds that worked both for Woodstox and the OOTB Java Stax implementation.  Those fixes are shipped in Java Client API 3.0.5.  Have you tried using the latest version?

Comment: As far as suggestions from @rjrudin about looking at HTTP traffic, I agree--that's how I would troubleshoot. I simply add this early in my code and thereafter I see full HTTP details coming out in std out or the logs (depending on how logging is configured): System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire", "debug");